# How to call a Javascript function in rails helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to rails. I have created a helper method with a loop. Inside the loop, I want to call a javascript function. Following is the code I have written. Any help would be appreciated.
Helper method

```
def test_helper param1
   param1.each do |x|
     "js_function(x.col1, x.col2)"
   end
end
```

in javascript file test.js

```
function js_function(x1, x2){

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helper File:

```
def test_helper param1
  javascript_tag(
    param1.map do |x|
      "js_function(\"#{j raw(x.col1)}\", \"#{j raw(x.col2)})\";"
    end.join("\n")
  )
end
```

View File:

```
<%= test_helper SOMEPARAM %>
```

Will Render HTML (Something Like):

```
<script>
  js_function(SOMEVALUEA1, SOMEVALUEA2);
  js_function(SOMEVALUEB1, SOMEVALUEB2);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Jay. I am getting an error in browser console when I used your suggestion.
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

//

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

//

Comment: Perhaps you might not need the outer <script>..</script> anymore. I'm updating my answer

Comment: If I don't  specify javascript_tag the function is displaying as a string in browser console with &#x27;&#x27; for empty params.
e.g., js_function((&#x27;&#x27;,  &#x27;abc&#x27;);

Comment: What was the full error message? I just tried this on my sample rails project, and I did not get any error message on the browser.

Comment: This worked fine. The only error message is end script tag is not appending

Comment: output in browseer console
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
js_function(SOMEVALUEA1, SOMEVALUEA2);
  js_function(SOMEVALUEB1, SOMEVALUEB2);
//

Comment: Where are you inserting `<%= test_helper SOMEPARAM %>`? Is that already inside a `<script>`...`</script>`?

Comment: Furthermore, `javascript_tag` only renders `<script>`, and not what you have just said `<script type='text/javascript'>`, so I am wondering if you have another outer `<script>`? or... that you have a different Rails version (perhaps old)? What Rails version are you currently on?

Comment: Rails 3.2.
<%= test_helper SOMEPARAM %> is placed inside a html.erb file

Comment: Rails 3.2 `javascript_tag` seems to be still the same as the latest Rails 5 from [here](https://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper/javascript_tag). So, I am not sure why yours is missing the ending: `</script>`

Comment: Wait you said that the end </script> tag is not appending. How did you know? Was this because the error message in the browser console did not include the end </script>? Or did you actually look into the HTML file, and see if it actually is missing the ending `</script>` tag? I'd just like to clear this up first, because probably the browser error message only shows you the the line where the error occurred.

Comment: What was the full exact error? Reason I'm asking is that I have a feeling there is a syntax error in your `"js_function(#{x.col1}, #{x.col2});"` (except that you replace this with the correct function name accordingly, or correct param names, etc, right?)

Comment: I got same doubt and removed my javascript and added "alert('All is good')"
Same error message in my console.

Comment: After you replace `"js_function(#{x.col1}, #{x.col2});"` with `"alert('All is good')"`, did it work? no more errors? (note that to be clear, I assumed you only replaced `"js_function...` with the `alert...`, and not the whole helper code.

Comment: Inside the loop i "alert('All is good')". Now in helper i have only loop and alert.

Comment: As you suggested I have checked any external script tag added. I found one and removed that now I can see the function is calling. I am getting &#x27; in my console instead of double quotes.

Comment: Oh you'll need to have `.html_safe` or `raw()`. I'm updating my answer. Just make sure that the `.col1` or `.col2` values will always be a safe string. Because if your users can edit this value, they might try to change this value into some javascript code, thereby opening up to potential security problems.

Comment: You'd probably also want to take care of properly escaping javascript strings  using `escape_javascript` or alias to `j`. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: Thank you so so much, Jay. raw is working perfectly. For empty params, it is still showing &#x27;

Comment: Perhaps there is a better and cleaner answer to this. But hopefully this works.

Comment: Hmm I if `param1` is empty array, then it should not be rendering anything. I just tried that out on my end.
No worries. Glad to help :)